# external access to a map

Tags: c++, dictionary, global-variables

Good afternoon everyone!  First let me say that I am not a C++ programmer, so replies need to take this into account.  I am working on a project that I inherited and I can't figure out how to pass a 'map' variable from one file into another.  Here's the makeup:

main.c

```
#include <string.h>
#include <map>
std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string,std::string> > MAPPEDINFO;
```

frame.c

```
#include <map>
extern std::map< std::string, std::map<std::string,std::string> > MAPPEDINFO;
//extern std::map MAPPEDINFO;
//extern *MAPPEDINFO;
```

I have tried various ways, but always end up with some type of error complaining about the use of 'std' or 'map' or something else.  I have researched for almost a full day, but can't figure it out.  Any help from C++ guru's would be most appreciated!

Thanks,
Dave

Comment: `#include <string.h>` should be `#include <string>` and why do your c++ source files have .c extension? That's just confusing =/

Comment: that's a good question.  Again, I am not the originator of the project, just the person that had this dropped in their lap. :)  So far I have not had any compile issues using <string.h> until I tried to export the map.  Is this just standard practice or something else?

Comment: I don't know how this used to be able to compile because `std::string` is defined in `<string>` not `<string.h>`, the latter header file contains the C library functions related to strings (strchr, ctrcpy, etc).

Comment: that is interesting because there isn't any reference to just <string> in any file related to the project!  I will adjust that to see if it makes any difference.  Is that standard in c++ or specific to operating systems?  I working in Linux.

Comment: [`<string>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/string) is a standard C++ header

Comment: I ended up adding <string> along with the other declarations and it appears to have resolved the problem.  If you want to create an answer suggesting this, I'll give you the vote Borgleader. :) Thanks for your help!